# load images from ftp to asp web page

Tags: asp.net

i have hosted my website on ftp containing folder named photogallery,now what i need to do
is when my page is requested all images from ftp folder photogallery should be display in a sequence.Thanks in advance.

```
string[] filesindirectory = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Photogallery"));
List<String> images = new List<string>(filesindirectory.Count());
foreach (string item in filesindirectory)
{
images.Add(String.Format("~/Photogallery/{0}", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(item)));
}
RepeaterImages.DataSource = images;
RepeaterImages.DataBind();
```

this is what i have done,but still images are not displaying.

Comment: Is this ftp on the same server? or some other ftp location

Comment: on same server, as like ~/photogallery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map your ftp folder to a virtual directory.

Use `Directory.GetFiles` to list all files.

You can bind this list to a repeater or list control and combine that with the virtual directory path to show the images